# iOS - Core Data from Extension when NSManagedObjectModel created programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to access `Core Data` from an app extension. I've already relocated the app's `Core Data` store to the shared app group directory. In the app, the `NSManagedObjectModel` and all the entities are created programmatically, so there is no `.mom` file. How do I get the `NSManagedObjectContext` in this case? Because of dependency issues, it's very difficult to share the code to create the model and entities with the extension.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you do in the app. Create a new context and set the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` property.

**RE: Comment**

> Well yes, but how do you get the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?
>   Creating the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator requires a
>   NSManagedObjectModel, but the NSManagedObjectModel is created in the
>   app programmatically. Can I just create NSManagedObjectModel the same
>   way as in the app?

You probably want the code that builds your Core Data stack in its own Framework to be included in both the App and App Extension. That way both the extension and app are able to build up the stack and access the persistent store that is in the share group.

> Also, the app's NSManagedObjectModel contains several entities, but in
>   the extension I only need one. Can the NSManagedObjectModel in the
>   extension only have that one entity and be able to communicate with
>   the database?

I wouldn't worry too much about it, modularize the Core Data code into a separate framework/target and go from there.

Comment: Well yes, but how do you get the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? Creating the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator requires a NSManagedObjectModel, but the NSManagedObjectModel is created in the app programmatically. Can I just create NSManagedObjectModel the same way as in the app?

Comment: Also, the app's NSManagedObjectModel contains several entities, but in the extension I only need one. Can the NSManagedObjectModel in the extension only have that one entity and be able to communicate with the database?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! We are eventually going to modularize the Core Data code, but it will require overhauling our entire app. For now, I'm planning on creating a separate database to hold just the entity I need from the extension. If I try to access this database from my extension using a NSManagedObjectModel containing just the one entity/store, would it work, or would it not work since the model would not be the same as the one that created the store?

Comment: This sounds a bit more complicated, you'd be managing two Core Data stacks. One for the extension and another for the app. Then you'd still need to solve the problem of getting data from one store to the other. To do that either the extension needs to be able to setup both stacks or the app does. Keep in mind your extension and app are not guaranteed to be running at the same time, they are entirely separate processes.